# MonoGame and Blender models size

Tags: blender, monogame

I want to display a flat terrain in my game. It will contain few square segments. For example 3x3. I create a plane in Blender, add textures and save it as fbx file. The problem is that I don't know how to calculate the size of this square in MonoGame. So for example, if I want square plane with 2.0f width in MonoGame, what width should it have in Blender?

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked a while ago, and it's probably better suited for the Game Development stackexchange, but I'd still like to answer it for posterity:

The scale of a model imported to an XNA game depends on the importer used to build the runtime content asset from the original content, as well as the game's camera matrices. For example, in the original XNA, back in the gold ol' days, the built-in FBX importer had options for X, Y, and Z scale and rotation. These settings, along with the scale of the camera matrices used during the game, determined the size of the model in-game.

Another common issue that people have when importing models from Blender is the rotation, which is also controlled by the content importer. Since Blender uses a right-hand Z-up coordinate system, and most XNA/Monogame programmers use a right-handed Y-up coordinate system, the rotation property had to be used.

That said, the fastest way to find out how to scale/rotate your models is generally to fiddle with the transformation methods of `Matrix`, until you find the right values by trial and error. **Compiling your game code is almost always faster than having to re-build your whole content project every time you change an importer property, especially if your models are very large or complicated.**